# PDFKit annotation url crash with non-nullable property that can be null

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

We are proud to use PDFKit in our app, but with some documents, a crash appeared, and is related to Links Handling.

We found one PDF document that provoque the weird crash : https://www.tinaja.com/glib/pdflink.pdf

The problem is that we fetch the URL of the annotations Links in the pdf, and the object PDFActionUrl have a `url: URL` property that is non-nullable.

But fact shows that is CAN be null, and provoke a crash when it is !

Proof of concept in Playgrounds:

```
import PDFKit

guard let pdfUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "pdflink", withExtension: "pdf") else {
    fatalError("no pdf url")
}

guard let pdf = PDFDocument(url: pdfUrl) else {
    fatalError("no pdf document")
}

guard let firstPage = pdf.page(at: 0) else {
    fatalError("no page")
}

firstPage.annotations[0].action // URL Action - (null)
firstPage.annotations[1].action // URL Action - (null)

guard let action = firstPage.annotations[0].action as? PDFActionURL else {
    fatalError("no action")
}

// PDFActionURL.url is non-nullable URL type
action.url // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

Does anyone know how we can check the value, and prevent the crash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, I have opened a bug report at Apple, and found a workaround, ugly, but working for now:

```
if let urlAction = annotation.action as? PDFActionURL {
  if urlAction.description.contains("URL Action - (null)") {
    throw Errors.unsupportedPdfAction
  }
  type = .url(url: urlAction.url)
}
```

Comment: The property is nullable since iOS 11.3 ; it's been fixed by Apple :)